# Script to find the date of all the sundays in a year

Tags: date

I wanted to print the dates of the 54 sundays in a year. i have written the  below script , but in the output im getting an error

Script:

```
req_date=`date +%m%d%Y`

for i in {1..54}

do
   NEXT_DATE=$(date +%m%d%Y -d "$req_date +  7*$i day")
   echo "$NEXT_DATE"
done
```

Output

```
+ for i in '{1..54}'
++ date +%m%d%Y -d '11132019 +  7*32 day'
date: invalid date ‘11132019 +  7*32 day’
+ NEXT_DATE=
+ echo ''

+ for i in '{1..54}'
++ date +%m%d%Y -d '11132019 +  7*33 day'
date: invalid date ‘11132019 +  7*33 day’
+ NEXT_DATE=
+ echo ''

+ for i in '{1..54}'
++ date +%m%d%Y -d '11132019 +  7*34 day'
date: invalid date ‘11132019 +  7*34 day’
+ NEXT_DATE=
+ echo ''

+ for i in '{1..54}'
++ date +%m%d%Y -d '11132019 +  7*35 day'
date: invalid date ‘11132019 +  7*35 day’
+ NEXT_DATE=
..
```

can someone help me with this ?

Comment: 11132019 is not a date format (it's also not a Sunday) 11/13/2019 would be better

Comment: irrespective of which day the script should return the days right ?

Comment: It tells you 4 times quite clearly `date: invalid date ‘11132019 +  7*35 day’` so I said try 11/13/2019 instead of 11132019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your script corrected.

- Sets **req_date** correctly dd/mm/yyy and to next sunday
- Uses bash syntax in date offset calculation
- starts loop at index 0 instead of 1, and therefore ends loop at 53 instead of 54.

```
req_date=`date +%m/%d/%Y -d sunday`

for i in {0..53}
do
    NEXT_DATE=$(date +%m%d%Y -d "$req_date +  $((7*i)) days")
    echo "$NEXT_DATE"
done
```

Comment: This helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In `ksh93`,

```
printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' '2020-01 '{1..52}'th Sunday'
```

Would give you the list of all 52 Sundays in 2020 (in a more useful and unambiguous `YYYY-MM-DD` format but you could always change to `%m%d%Y` if you really (really?) wanted to).

```
printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' '2023-01 '{1..53}'th Sunday'
```

for the 53 ones of 2023.

There can't be 54 Sundays in a year.

A year could have 54 *weeks* two of which unfinished, which is why `date +%W` can take values 00 to 53, but at least one of the Sundays of week 00 or 53 will be in an adjacent year (and week 00 or 53 could belong to more than one year; compare with the ISO week number (`%V`) which avoids it and runs from 01 to 53).

Answer (score 1):

my answer  all Thursdays between start date and 30 weeks using sequence choosing the first Thursday

```
paul@debian:~$         
strt="2023/06/01"
for i in `seq 0 30`;
        do
                echo "datum  $i $(date -d "${strt}+${i} week  " +"%A/%d/%m/%Y" )"
        done

datum  0 Thursday/01/06/2023
datum  1 Thursday/08/06/2023
datum  2 Thursday/15/06/2023
datum  3 Thursday/22/06/2023
datum  4 Thursday/29/06/2023
datum  5 Thursday/06/07/2023
datum  6 Thursday/13/07/2023
datum  7 Thursday/20/07/2023
datum  8 Thursday/27/07/2023
datum  9 Thursday/03/08/2023
datum  10 Thursday/10/08/2023
datum  11 Thursday/17/08/2023
datum  12 Thursday/24/08/2023
datum  13 Thursday/31/08/2023
datum  14 Thursday/07/09/2023
datum  15 Thursday/14/09/2023
datum  16 Thursday/21/09/2023
datum  17 Thursday/28/09/2023
datum  18 Thursday/05/10/2023
datum  19 Thursday/12/10/2023
datum  20 Thursday/19/10/2023
datum  21 Thursday/26/10/2023
datum  22 Thursday/02/11/2023
datum  23 Thursday/09/11/2023
datum  24 Thursday/16/11/2023
datum  25 Thursday/23/11/2023
datum  26 Thursday/30/11/2023
datum  27 Thursday/07/12/2023
datum  28 Thursday/14/12/2023
datum  29 Thursday/21/12/2023
datum  30 Thursday/28/12/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid trouble with week 0 or 54 - depending on your standard, you could just loop over all days and select all Sundays:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get day of year number for last day of year
total_days=$(date -d'2019-12-31' +%j)

#loop over all days and select Sundays
for (( i=0 ; i<${total_days} ; i++ )) ; do
  date -d"2019-01-01 + ${i}" +"%a %Y-%m-%d" | grep Su | cut -d' ' -f2
done
```

You also MUST specify your start date in your `req_date` you want all Sundays of a year with the `-d` option. (Unless you want the following 54 Sundays from `req_date` as starting point.)

---

Regarding the problem as specified in your question:

As already mentioned in the comments, your input format is wrong. Possible date input strings are a bit more complicated to explain and also non-intuitive so some extend, but explained en detail in `info "date input formats"`. This is a very long description. As you use no hyphens or slashes, here just from

> *29.8 Pure numbers in date strings*
>
> If the decimal number is of the form YYYYMMDD and no other calendar
>   date item (*note Calendar date items::) appears before it in the date
>   string, then YYYY is read as the year, MM as the month number and DD as
>   the day of the month, for the specified calendar date.

As such your date `11132019` is Year 1113 Month 20 and Day 19 which does not exist, thus fails.

Personally I prefer yyyy-mm-dd to exclude any confusion between US and other date formats as you can see in the above script.